# ¿Cómo pongo un label en tkinter que se actualize segun su texto cambie?

Tags: python, tkinter, os

Usando Python y tkinter.

Estoy haciendo un programa en el que necesito que cuando pulse un botón, este cambie el valor de una variable y que esa variable se actualice en un label.

Estoy haciendo un programa en el que necesito que cuando pulse un botón, este cambie el valor de una variable y que esa variable se actualice en un label.

Estoy haciendo un programa en el que necesito que cuando pulse un botón, este cambie el valor de una variable y que esa variable se actualice en un label.

He mirado a ver si con after() funcionaba, pero no.

Este es el código:

```
import tkinter as tk

wn = tk.Tk()
wn.geometry("500x500+735+200")
wn.resizable(0, 0)
wn.title("Program")
wn.iconbitmap("images/icon.ico")

state = False

def encendido():
    state = True

def apagado():
    state = False

def printing():
    if state == True:
        value = "Activado"
    else:
        value = "Desactivado"
    etiqueta1.config(text=value)
    
etiqueta1 = tk.Label(wn, text="estado")
etiqueta1.pack()

btn = tk.Button(wn, text="Pusla para desactivar", command=apagado()).pack()
btn2 = tk.Button(wn, text="Pusla para activar", command=encendido()).pack()

see_state = tk.Label(wn, text=printing())



wn.after(1000, printing())
wn.mainloop()
```

EDIT

Despues de mucho buscar e intentar lo conseguí sin after() ni na! :D

Lo conseguí este es el codigo:

```
import tkinter as tk
import customtkinter as ctk

#-->VENTANA
wn = tk.Tk()
wn.geometry("600x400+735+300")
wn.resizable(0, 0)
wn.title("Programa")

#-->DEFINICIONES
def apagado():
    estado = "Apagado"
    etiqueta["text"] = estado

def encender():
    estado = "Encendido"
    etiqueta["text"] = estado

#-->BOTONES Y ETIQUETAS
boton1 = tk.Button(wn, text="Apagar", command= apagado, borderwidth=0, background="#ABB2B9",fg="black", height=10, width=10, font="Calibri", activebackground="#2C3E50")
boton1.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
boton2 = tk.Button(wn, text="Encender", command=encender, borderwidth=0, background="#ABB2B9",fg="black", height=10, width=10, font="Calibri", activebackground="#2C3E50")
boton2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
etiqueta = tk.Label(wn)
etiqueta.pack()

#-->LOOP
wn.mainloop()
```

Comment: Usa una [variable de control](https://python-para-impacientes.blogspot.com/2016/02/variables-de-control-en-tkinter.html) y modifica esa variable, te hará más facil la vida. Peeero el verdadero error está en executar (poner parentesis al lado) la función cuando en realidad debería estar sin ser ejecutada. En realidad, estás pasando un objeto que representa a una función al botón. Si piensas eso, probablemente no te vuelva a ocurrir este error.

Comment: Cuando se ejecuta una función en el argumento command y esta función devuelve None, tkinter interpreta que el botón no debe tener ningún comando.

Comment: Lo he conseguido!